# How to get or view these extraneous bytes in "Corrupt JPEG data: 22 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9" warning?

Tags: steganography, mogrify

I am using **steghide** tool to extract any hidden message from jpeg file. Original image is opened without any problem. But **steghide** gives me this warning:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 22 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

Image still opens with this corruption.

I tried

```
mogrify -set comment 'Image rewritten with ImageMagick' myimage.jpg
```

It removed that corrupt data and image still works fine but I want to know what that 22 bytes corrupt data is. Is there any way to get or view that corrupt data?

Comment: Any hex viewer or editor would let you examine the raw bytes.

Comment: Did you figure out how to view these bytes?

Comment: No. I can read whole file that's it. I think you should find yourself